# Where does log4net write log files when debugging a web application through Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-applications, log4net

I'm trying to add log4net logging to a web application I'm writing. I've got this in a web service method:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();  
log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Methods));

log.Info("Some information");
```

And this in the web.config file:

```xml
<configSections>
  <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
</system.web>
<log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollFileAppender">
        <file value="log.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

I was expecting the log file to appear in the bin\ directory when I debug it through Visual Studio 2010, but nothing is written there. The method runs successfully without any exceptions, but I can't find the log file. Any ideas as to where it should appear?

Edit - Some extra info:
According to the notification area icon, the ASP.Net Development Server is running in:

```
C:\Users\jpope\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\
```

The permissions on this directory and the \bin\ sub-directory both give SYSTEM, me and Administrators full control, and no one else any access. The log file is not in the directory shown above or the \bin\ sub-directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to wade into some low-level stuff, it might be interesting to see what [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) thinks the web server process is trying to write to.  At least it would be more fun than wading through the log4net documentation.

Comment: No mention of the file whatsoever in Process Monitor, so I guess the configuration is wrong somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should set the asp.net user has the write right for you web directory.

Comment: @x16man: Is that the user that the debug web service runs under?

Comment: @x16man: I've looked at that bin directory and according to windows only SYSTEM, me and Administrators have access to it, and we all have full control. Does the debug web server run from a different directory?

Comment: <file value="log.txt" /> your log file will be created in the webservice's folder,not the bin folder <file value="bin\log.txt">,you can <file value="log\log.txt">.and you need check the webservice's folder. if the aspnet user has the full control.

Comment: @x16man: I've checked the applications folder and the ASP.NET user has no control at all on that directory, so I'm not sure it's running as that user.

Comment: @x16man: After a bit more investigation, it turns out the the ASP.Net Development Server runs under your current user account (including with admin privileges if you are an administrator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a configuration problem. Switching to a `FileAppender` instead of a RollFileAppender works fine. Now I need to find out what's wrong with the `RollFileAppender` configuration...

Edit: It's a `RollingFileAppender`, not a `RollFileAppender`.